# Re-instantiate angular controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have a directive that appends an element to the body. This element has an ng-controller on it, however when the element is appended to the body, the controller is not instantiated. What is the best way to append an element with a controller so that the controller is instantiated each time it append. NOTE: I will also have to remove the element at some point. Which would be the best way to do this?

```
<div my-directive>
    <!--this element will be removed by the directive and then appended to the body-->
    <div ng-controller="MyController"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You would need to re `$compile` it after appending

Comment: how would i get the scope of the ngController to compile it with?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to move an element into the DOM? They are many ways to solve this but it depends on the context.

Comment: i'm trying to mimic Foundation 4 reveal modal where it removes the element from the DOM and appends it to the body. I can append no problem but i need the controller to re-instatiate every time.